# HttpClient hanging in long-running service

Tags: c#, azure

We have a service deployed in AKS that makes HTTP requests to an external API outside of the cluster. The path of the request is AKS -> API Management -> ExpressRoute -> API.

We have been encountering an issue where all requests from an instance of the service will hang when calling the external API. The requests never reach the API. Due to the timeouts that we have configured, the requests will be cancelled after 10 seconds. We most recently saw this on an instance of the service that had been running for over 30 days without any issues. Restarting the instance resolves the issue.

We use `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` (6.0.0) to register the API client class with the following code:

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IMyApiClient, MyApiClient>();
```

Our API client looks like this:

```
public class MyApiClient : IMyApiClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyApiClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task CallApi(CancellationToken ctx)
    {
        await _httpClient.GetAsync("api-uri", ctx);
    }
}
```

Obviously there is complexity in the hops between AKS and the API, however, I first want to understand if we are doing anything wrong with HttpClient. As far as I can tell, we are following the reccommended usage.

We are unable to reproduce this issue locally and we have no additional logs as the requests are simply taking a long time and then being cancelled, there are no actual errors.

Comment: By Any chance, are you calling your Async calls Synchronously? This often happens due to deadlock.

Comment: @CodeNameJack we are calling everything asynchronously end-to-end.

@mahdigholami I don't think your comment makes sense. `CallApi` is not a controller endpoint, it's a method that calls an API.